# (RoomDatabase) Update database values ​from assets without losing user data

Tags: android, database, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-room

In my android (Android Studio) application the data is preloaded from a database in the assets folder whit RoomDatabase.

```
   val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, NormRoomDatabase::class.java, "legislacion_database")
                .createFromAsset("legislacion.db")                    
                .addCallback(NormDatabaseCallback(scope))
                .build()
```

To update the data of the application database I have to update the data of the database of the assets folder and I update its version to 2.
So that the new data is loaded I update the version of the database in Room to 2 as well,
and I add the following line:

```
.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
```

By doing this, those of the db in the application are updated with the data of the assets db.
So far everything is fine.

The problem is that doing this also deletes the data that users have added in the apk, such as comments and favorites.

How can I update my application with the new asset data without losing the data that users have added?
Is this possible?
I DO NOT WANT TO UPDATE THE DATABASE SCHEME, ONLY THE VALUES.

Comment: It looks as now the old database is completely replaced by the new one from assets.

Comment: As you only have to add some values then make your own txt/csv file with the values you want to add and put this file in assets. Then at runtime read the values from csv and add to the databas in the normal way.

Comment: I had that idea in mind but I was hoping room would give me a way to do it